# Best way to get N numbers from range betwen 2 (big) numbers

Tags: php, numbers, range

Hello I need to get N numbers from range between 2 big numbers, without the start and end numbers.
The (N) numbers must be on equal intervals... I will try to explain with small numbers:

```
<?php
$rangeStart = 0;
$rangeEnd = 100;
$n = 9;
```

In this example i need to get 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90

I have try with 'for loop' but it is veeery slow, because I'm using range like 1207083600 ~ 1275512399

Will appreciate any help.

=====

This is what I call slow http://jsfiddle.net/pbF7N/1/
The start and end are timestamps and I need to extract 10 dates...

Comment: Slow? I can´t imagein. Please show what you did with the for loop.

Comment: nabuchodonossor -> http://jsfiddle.net/pbF7N/1/

Comment: you are creating an array with nearly 7 million entries. this would need a lot of memory (I´m not exactly shure, but 6.84 millions * keysize 19 byte?).

Comment: and you know, you could use a step value instead of ++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
function nrange($num, $start, $end)
{
        $out = array(); $i = 0;
        $interval = floor(($end - $start) / ($num + 1));
        while ($i++ < $num )
                $out[] = $start + $i * $interval;

        return $out;
}
```

Comment: Same error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in ------------ tested on range 1207083600 - 1275512399

Comment: What are you doing with these numbers? Maybe break them down into sub ranges?

Comment: also ... function nrange($start, $end, $step) {
    $substraction = $end - $start;
    if($substraction < $step) return range($start, $end);
    $h = round($substraction/$step);
    for($i=$start; $i<$end;$i+=$h) {
 $a[] = $i;
    }
    return $a;
}

Answer (score 8):

[range()](http://www.php.net/manual/function.range.php) with its optional 3rd parameter to specify the step size...

```
range(10, 90, 10);

$range = range(10, 90, 10);
print_r($range);
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 30
    [3] => 40
    [4] => 50
    [5] => 60
    [6] => 70
    [7] => 80
    [8] => 90
)
```

Comment: Ok I missed somehow this function. Seems to be ok BUT gives me error like :  "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in ..." 
Range I was testing on is start:1207083600 end:1275512399 (yes numbers are timestamps)

Comment: Maybe you need to scale everything down before plugging it in... E.g., rather than going from 0 to 100 in steps on 10, just go from 0 to 10 in steps of 1, then multiple each result by 10.

Comment: Down-voting because you didn't explain the values of the range() arguments

Comment: @jlb, the documentation is linked so that anyone unfamiliar can look up the parameters

Comment: Ray I think I can't scale everything down because these are timestamps and I believe that the scale up will be not very accurate ... ?

Comment: That's right, you'd like a little precision; e.g., if your timestamp is in seconds, this technique might make you approximate to, say, the nearest minute (depending on your scale factor)

Comment: The other option would be to shift, rather than to scale. E.g., run the process for 0 .. 68428799, then add 1207083600 to each of your numbers.

Comment: @jib You're free to vote as you wish, but (1) I did explain the crucial 3rd param to `range()`, and (2) the function is linked to documentation.

Comment: @Michael I was referring to the fact that values for your arguments range(10, 90, 10); don't *directly* correlate to the values presented in the question

Comment: @jib They correspond exactly to the OP's requested output: _In this example i need to get 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90_

Comment: @Michael, what was lacking was the explanation for how to get `10`, given `0`, `100`, and `9`. You might consider adding an formula for this like the `($rangeEnd - $rangeStart) / $n` expression in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider first your example case. Your numbers broke up the range `[0..100)` into 10 equal intervals, `[0..10)`, `[10, 20)`, etc. up to `[90..100)`.

Notice that the number of intervals is `$n+1`. So you see that each interval is of length `($rangeEnd - $rangeStart) / $n`.

Using this information, you can use [range](http://www.php.net/manual/function.range.php) to step across `$interval` numbers at a time, i.e.,

```
$interval = ($rangeEnd - $rangeStart) / $n;
$range = range($rangeStart, $rangeEnd, $interval);
```